# Mongo db how to save an object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

Below code gives error and it says School class must implement DBObject interface. The problem is that this interface has tons of methods. I have nearly 100 class and I don't want to write millions of methods. Is there any easy way to save an object?

```
DBCollection table = db.getCollection("school");

School document = new School();
table.insert(document);
```

Comment: Would it be an option to extend [BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/1.3/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html) or similar?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes I was searching for it. thanks.

Comment: Have you considered the use of a mapper framework, such spring-data or morphia?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of implementing `DBObject` or extending one of the existing implementations like `BasicDBObject`, you could have all objects which can be saved in the database have a method `public DBObject toDBObject()` which creates and returns a `DBObject` representation of the object. The `BasicDBObject` is a `Map<String, Object>` which handles the object data as key/value pairs, so it is a good candidate for this.

For a more generic solution, you could use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to create a method which can convert any Java object into a DBObject. To have more control over this, you could make up some annotations, add them to your classes and have your conversion method check them.

Now you have created your own object mapping framework for MongoDB. But why reinvent the wheel when others have already done it? So before you do this, check out if the existing mapping frameworks like [morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia) fulfill your use-case - they likely do and will save you hours of programming and weeks of debugging.

[opinion]

I usually despise object-relational mappers in the context of relational databases because of the [impedance mismatch problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch), but for heterogeneous databases like MongoDB they make a lot more sense, because you can store objects which have the same base-class but also some different class-specific fields in the same <strike>table</strike> collection without any ugly workarounds.

[/opinion]